# List only records populated with Capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara

Friends helped me with a solution that validates if there are [active/inactive] records in the list. When I list the records using pp capybara also returns blank lines. How do I disregard empty records?

```rb
def validate_active_inactive_records
  expect(page).to have_css("td:nth-child(5)", :text => /^(ACTIVE|INACTIVE)$/) 
 
  # ***listing records***
  page.all('.tvGrid tr > td:nth-child(5)').each do |td|
    puts td.text
  end
end
```

```html
<table width="100%" class="tvGrid">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="1" class="tvHeader">Id</th>
    <th colspan="1" class="tvHeader">Code</th>
    <th colspan="1" class="tvHeader">Description</th>
    <th colspan="1" class="tvHeader">Operational Center</th>
    <th colspan="1" class="tvHeader">Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tvRowEmpty">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tvRowEmpty">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tvRowEmpty">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tvRowEmpty">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tvRowEmpty">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tvRowEmpty">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tvRowEmpty">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Are you trying to validate that all rows of the grid contain the text ACTIVE or INACTIVE, or are you just trying to extract some information from the rows that do contain that text, and ignore the rows that don't contain that text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to remove the rows with the class `tvRowEmpty` from your search results? If so, you can use the `:not` operator in your finder:

```
def validate_active_inactive_records
  expect(page).to have_css("td:nth-child(5)", :text => /^(ACTIVE|INACTIVE)$/) 
 
  # ***listing records***
  page.all('.tvGrid tr:not(.tvRowEmpty) > td:nth-child(5)').each do |td|
    puts td.text
  end
end
```

If you want to exclude any `td` that just contains `&nbsp;` you could use the following finder with a regex that filters tags containing only whitespace characters:

```
page.all('.tvGrid tr > td:nth-child(5)', text: /[\s]^*/).each
```

Comment: Wow very good, what font do you use to do this?

Comment: @Elis https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks